# How to use direnv with python venv?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, python-venv, direnv

I have this line in my `.envrc`

```
source python3-venv/bin/activate
```

I basically created a python3 venv inside the folder where the `.envrc` is located.

However even through the .evnrc is executed (e.g. all now env variables are set correctly when I enter this directoy), the venv is not activated.

When I do `which python3`, it shows `/usr/local/bin/python3` instead of `<path to my current folder>/python-venv/bin/python3`

If I run the `source` line manually, the bash prompt will switch to `(python3-venv) my-workstation:working-folder antkong$` as expected.

How can I get the `python-venv` correctly activated?

I am running it in MacOS Mojave.

Comment: You mentioned `python3-venv` vs `python-env`

Comment: https://github.com/direnv/direnv/wiki/Python

Comment: @Hatshepsut just typo. Fixed

Comment: Is `layout python3` as contents of `.envrc` nowadays sufficient?

Comment: @AnnevanRossum Yes, it is. Do you know, by any chance, how one can deactivate the virtual environment without exiting the project directory or shell? `deactivate` is unavailable.

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov I don't know what's so important to stay in the same directory? With `direnv deny` and going out and into that directory would be fine.

Comment: @AnnevanRossum Yes, after some getting used to I got it that the tool is nice and bulletproof enough :) . My request is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the venv then rebuild the venv

```
python3 -m venv python3-venv
```

It seems to fix the issue.